# contentComponent not working React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native

As it says in the title, contentComponent not working. I cant quite figure out why it is not rendering the content in contentcomponent.

It shows the screens 1 2 and logout that I have in the drawer navigator instead of it. Any suggestions is appreciated?
Routes.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {
        createAppContainer,
        createSwitchNavigator,
        createStackNavigator,
        createBottomTabNavigator,
        createDrawerNavigator
    } from 'react-navigation';
import { SideNavigation } from './SideNavigation';

    export const SignedOut = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: {
            screen: LoginForm,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            }
        },
        Register: {
            screen: RegisterForm
        },
        VerifyPhone: {
            screen: PhoneVerify,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerLeft: null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Login"
    }
);

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Main: Main
        }),
    },
    Events: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Events: Events
        }),
    },
    Shop: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Shop: Shop
        }),
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Profile: Profile
        }),
    },
});

export const Stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: {
            screen: SideNavigation,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
            },
        },
        DefaultScreen: {
            screen: Main,
        }
    }
);

export const createRootNavigator = (loggedin) => {
    return createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            SignedIn: {
                screen: Stack
            },
            SignedOut: {
                screen: SignedOut
            },
        },
        {
            //initialRouteName: loggedin ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
            initialRouteName: "SignedIn"
        }
    ));
};
```

SideNavigation.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Stack } from "./Routes";

export const SideNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        home: Stack
    },
    {
        contentComponent: (props) => {
           return <Drawer {...props} >
                <ScrollView>
                    <SafeAreaView
                        forceInset={{top: 'always', horizontal: 'never'}}
                    >
                        <Text
                            onPress={() => {
                                props.navigation.navigate('Screen1');
                                props.navigation.closeDrawer();
                            }}
                        >
                            Testing Side 1
                        </Text>
                        <Text
                            onPress={() => {
                                props.navigation.navigate('Screen2');
                                props.navigation.closeDrawer();
                            }}
                        >
                            Testing side 2
                        </Text>
                    </SafeAreaView>
                </ScrollView>
            </Drawer>
        },
    }
);
```

Edit: Code has been updated. i am now getting an error that says 'home'must be a React component.

Answer (score 1):

give your custom component as a separated component file, like this:

```
import Drawer from "./somewhere"; 
 const Stack = createStackNavigator(
{

    DefaultScreen: {
        screen: Main,
    }
}
);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    home: Stack <<<<this is an address of the stack navigator you should created above
}, {
        contentComponent: (props) => {

            return <Drawer {...props} /> <<<<Drawer
        },
        drawerPosition: 'right',
        drawerType: 'slide',
        drawerWidth: width * 0.8
    }
)
```

more logical and cleaner... but don't forget to give drawer to your app container:

```
 return createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            SignedIn: {
                screen: DrawerNavigato//not stack 
            },
            SignedOut: {
                screen: SignedOut
            },
        },
        {
            //initialRouteName: loggedin ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
            initialRouteName: "SignedIn"
        }
    ));
```

Comment: I get the error, "home must be a react component" error.

Comment: because you defined stack lower then drawer in your code. create it in top of that

Comment: I dont think so, I cleaned up the file as you suggested and its still giving me the error. I cant have it lower than the drawer in my code if the component is being imported. I also updated my code.

Comment: however i edited my answer ... you can test it if you think its useful

Comment: Inside of Stack drawer should be DrawerNavigation correct?

Comment: excuse me i edited a gain ....no you dont need give drawerNavigation inside stack

Comment: Yeah, that definitely broke the navigation, Theres no connection to the stack and the sidebar therefore when I try to open it, it cannot find the sidebar. I think I will investigate this further.

Comment: yes but it solves if you give your DrawerNavigator to SwitchNavigator instead of give stack to that....try it :)